# Does the ABI persist any more error information than an HRESULT?

Tags: error-handling, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

While porting a regular C++ class to a Windows Runtime class, I hit a fairly significant road block. My C++ class reports certain error conditions by throwing custom error objects. This allows clients to conveniently filter on exceptions, documented in the public interface.

I cannot seem to find a reliable way to pass enough information across the ABI to replicate the same fidelity<sup>1</sup> using the Windows Runtime. Under the assumption, that an `HRESULT` is the only generalized error reporting information, I have evaluated the following options:

1. The 'obvious' choice: Map the exception condition to any of the predefined [HRESULT values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/705fb797-2175-4a90-b5a3-3918024b10b8). While this technically works (presumably), there is no way at the call site to distinguish between errors originating from the implementation, and errors originating from callees of the implementation.
2. Invent custom `HRESULT`s. If [this layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a) still applies to the Windows Runtime, I could easily set the *Customer* bit and go crazy with *my* 27 bits worth of error code representation. This works, until someone else does the same. I'm not aware of any way to attribute an `HRESULT` to an interface, which would solve this ambiguity.
3. Even if either of the above could be made to work as intended, throwing [hresult_error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/hresult-error)s as prescribed, the call site would still be at the mercy of the language projection. While C# seemingly allows to pass any `System.Exception`(-derived) error object across the ABI, and have them re-thrown at the call site, C++/WinRT only supports some 14 distinct exception types (see [throw_hresult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/throw-hresult)).

With neither of these options allowing for sufficiently complete error information to cross the ABI, it seems that an `HRESULT` simply may not be enough. Does the Windows Runtime have any provisioning to allow for additional (arbitrary) error information to cross the ABI?

---

<sup>1</sup> *I'm not strictly interested in passing actual C++ exceptions across. Instead, I'm looking for a way to allow clients to **uniquely** identify documented error conditions, in a natural way. Passing custom Windows Runtime error types would be fine.*

Comment: It sounds like `RoOriginateError` is what you're looking for. You can store a custom string for your error and the caller that receives a bad hresult can retrieve it via `GetRestrictedErrorInfo` call. This is how exception text shows up in C# even when the exception is thrown from C++/CX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options here. Our general API guidance for Windows Runtime APIs that have well-defined, expected failure modes is that failure information should be part of the normal parameters and return value. We would normally create a TryDoSomething API in this situation and provide extended error information via either a return or out parameter. This works best for us due to the fact that there's no consistent way to map exceptions across all languages. This is a topic we hope to revisit more in [xlang](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang) in the future.

HRESULTs are usable with a caveat. HRESULT values can be a nuisance in anything but C++, where you need to redefine them locally because you can't just use the header. They will generate exceptions in most languages, so if this is common, you'll be creating debugger noise for your components' clients.

The last option allows you to transit a language-specific exception stored in a COM object across the ABI boundary (and up the COM logical stack, including across marshalled calls). In practice it will only be usable by C++ code compiled with the same compiler, settings, and type definitions as the component itself. E.g. passing it from a component compiled with VC to a component compiled with Clang could potentially lead to memory corruption.

Assuming I haven't scared you off, you'll want to look at [RoOriginateLanguageException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/roerrorapi/nf-roerrorapi-rooriginatelanguageexception). It allows you to wrap the exception in a COM object and store it with other winrt error data in the TLS. We use this in projections to enable exceptions thrown within a callback to propagate to the outer code using the same projection in a controlled way that unwinds safely through other code potentially written using other languages or tools. This is how the support in C# and other languages is implemented.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Reading this answer I realized, that I haven't been specific enough in describing my requirements. I'm assuming that you are referring to a `std::exception_ptr` object stored in a COM object in your last option. That'd totally defeat most all of the benefits we get from establishing an ABI, and it's not quite what I'm looking for. What's interesting, apparently we *can* have a COM exception object travel the ABI (in addition to the `HRESULT`). So in theory we could have `throw MyWinRTEx{};` and `catch(MyWinRTEx const&)` at the call site (provided we got language projection support).

Comment: Would this actually be possible in practice, or have I overlooked something? If this is indeed possible, is it something that is being evaluated for a future C++/WinRT projection?

Comment: WinRT doesn't have a way to do this yet today, but there's no reason why it wouldn't be possible. That's what I'd like to revisit in the xlang project (which has both WinRT and xlang tooling). It's a bit more complicated because not all languages support exception objects as their natural error handling path, but the basic gist is that if you're in such a language, why not deal in natural exception types?

Comment: When you say *"WinRT"*, are you referring to the Windows Runtime, or the C++/WinRT language projection? And when you refer to the xlang project, does that imply that changes will eventually make it into C++/WinRT as well?

Comment: I was referring to the Windows Runtime type system and OS support. The support for a projected exception is unlikely to come back to WinRT. It's not impossible, but unlikely.